# Разделить месяц на недели tsql

Tags: sql-server

Мне приходит дата вида @periodId int=201801, где 2018 это год а 01 это месяц. 
Эти данные приводятся к формату datetime следующим образом

```
declare @periodIdDatetimeFormat datetime 
select @periodIdDatetimeFormat = convert(varchar(4),@periodId/100)+
'-'+convert(varchar(2),@periodId%100)+'-'+'01'
```

В результате получается дата вида "2018-01-01". Необходимо вывести все недели данного месяца в формате 01.01.2018-07.01.2018, причем первое число в неделе должно соответствовать четвергу, а последнее пятнице (01.01-чт, 07.01-пт). Есть ли какой то способ это сделать средствами tsql?

Comment: Вам поможет DATEPART() и DATEADD()

Comment: А что с неделями, которые начинаются или заканчиваются в другом месяце? И какая версия SQL Server?

Comment: Вообще, выберите какой-то реальный месяц и добавьте в вопрос результат, который хотите получить, потому что "неделя", которая начинается в четверг, а заканчивается в пятницу - это не неделя, а 2 или 9 дней и такого ` (01.01-чт, 07.01-пт)` быть в одном и том же месяце не может

Comment: Да, вы правы. В этом и суть, если 1ое число месяца выпадает, допустим (как в апреле 2019 на понедельник), то мне нужна неделя с пятницы предыдущего месяца (29 марта) по четверг апреля (29.03-4.04). Возможно я не до совсем верно выразился в постановке вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вот такой выход

```
    DECLARE @periodId DATETIME
set language russian
SET @periodId = '2019-01-04'

declare @firstWeekOfMonth datetime
select @firstWeekOfMonth = (case when datepart(WEEKDAY,@periodId) < 5 then dateadd(dd,-(datepart(weekday,@periodId)+2),@periodId)
            when datepart(WEEKDAY,@periodId) = 5 then dateadd(dd,0,@periodId) 
            else dateadd(dd,5-(datepart(weekday,@periodId)),@periodId) 
        end) 
select @firstWeekOfMonth
```